# How to escape $$ sign when writing bash?

Tags: bash, shell

How to escape $$ sign when writing bash ?

if I want to write `$let` I do this:  `\"\$let\"` and it works fine.

but if I want to write `$$building.gateways`, how do I do it? 
Currently trying as : `\"\$\$building.gateways\"` but not working.

Below line for example:

```
COMMAND+=",\"in\": { \"\$let\": {\"vars\": {\"gateway\": {\"\$arrayElemAt\": [{\"\$filter\": {\"input\": \"\$\$building.gateways\",\"cond\": {\"\$eq\": [\"\$\$this._id\",\"\$gatewayId\"]}}},0]}}"
```

UPDATED:
I am trying to convert below mongo query syntax into bash script.

```
device: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            building: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$accountInfo.buildings",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$buildingId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                gateway: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$building.gateways",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this._id",
                            "$gatewayId"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$$gateway.devices",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this._id",
                          "$deviceId"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This is what I have right now, but its not working. (I think part with `$$` fails and it returns null). the query works in mongo shell so query is correct.

```
  \"device\": {\"\$let\": {\"vars\": {\"building\": {\"\$arrayElemAt\": [{\"\$filter\": {\"input\": \"\$accountInfo.buildings\",\"cond\": {\"\$eq\": [\"\$\$this._id\",\"\$buildingId\"]}}},0]}},
          \"in\": {\"\$let\": {\"vars\": {\"gateway\": {\"\$arrayElemAt\": [{\"\$filter\": {\"input\": \"\$\$building.gateways\",\"cond\": {\"\$eq\": [\"\$\$this._id\",\"\$gatewayId\"]}}},0]}},
              \"in\": {\"\$arrayElemAt\": [{\"\$filter\": {\"input\": \"\$\$gateway.devices\",\"cond\": { \"\$eq\": [\"\$\$this._id\", \"\$deviceId\"]}}},0]}}}}}
```

Thanks

Comment: The line you show looks ok to me (`\$\$building.gateways`).  What is the specific issue you are having?

Comment: Have a look, I have updated question with some more details.

Comment: You don't need *any* of those escapes if you put data that's supposed to be literal in single quotes rather than double quotes. That is to say, `'$$building.gateways'` works fine (when used in an unquoted context; put it inside double quotes instead of exiting them and they control).

Comment: What @CharlesDuffy said, except if you have literal single quotes `'` it will need special handling.  So just surround the entire string in its current format (including newlines) with a pair of `'` `'`.

Comment: @rtx13, do you see any single quotes in the OP's code? I'm on a phone, sure, but I haven't spotted them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no none in the show code.  More of an "in case of"...

Comment: @rtx13: I stumbled over a similar problem recently and learned that if you prepend the opening `'` by a `$`, you can use `\'` inside the string to escape a single quote. For example: `$'this has $$ and \' in it'`

Comment: @user1934428 good point, but you have to remember that many more escapes are interpreted in these special strings.  For instance `\n` is not preserved as the sequence of two characters `'\'` and `'n'`, rather it is converted to a single newline character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole thing in single quotes.

```
query='
device: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            building: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$accountInfo.buildings",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$buildingId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                gateway: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$building.gateways",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this._id",
                            "$gatewayId"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$$gateway.devices",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this._id",
                          "$deviceId"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
'
echo "$query"
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/7YB0Ll

Comment: Or you use `IFS= read -r -d '' query <<'EOF' ... ... EOF` so nothing gets in the way of this long multi-line literal.